# Trying to get a mysql table id row into php variable to base futher mysql queries from it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am programming in a PHP, HTML and SQL and got stuck in some part of my project.

In the following code I tried to recieve an string that is meant to represent a name of a movie from a textbox after a button press. I then tried to search for ID of that film and then in everyother table where that ID is present I tried to remove all data tied to that ID then remove the data about the movie from the main table itself. Yet I run in tons of different errors I can't handle whenever I try another approach.

Could someone point me a nice way to remove all table records about a movie with ID for example 3 when the movie name is The Green Mile?

```
<?php
IF ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bazus");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysql_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
$tytul = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tytul']);
$id = "SELECT id FROM filmy WHERE tytul=$tytul";
$dana = mysql_query($id);
$film_przyznano =  "DELETE FROM przyznana WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$premiera = "DELETE FROM premiera WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$obsada = "DELETE FROM obsada WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$film_gatunek = "DELETE FROM film_gatunek WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$rezyseria = "DELETE FROM rezyseria WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$scenariusz = "DELETE FROM scenariusz WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
$film_producent = "DELETE FROM film_producent WHERE filmy_id='$dana'";
//mysql_query($film_przyznano);
//mysql_query($obsada);
//mysql_query($premiera);
//mysql_query($film_gatunek);
//mysql_query($rezyseria);
//mysql_query($scenariusz);
//mysql_query($film_producent);
/*$sql="DELETE FROM filmy WHERE tytul='$tytul'";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "1 record deleted";

$tytul="";*/
mysql_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
}
?>

<div id="remove">
<form action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' method='post'>
<input type="text" name="tytul">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, youre mixing up `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. They arent interlocking libraries, you habe to choose one or the other.

Comment: And a note: you dont fetch the data for `$dana` so when you set `$dana = mysql_query` it returns a boolean (true/false, 1/0, etc) and not your movie id

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you code is good. What you are lacking is error handling. If line 13 does not return a result, then $dana is equal to nothing, which will toss an error for all the result of your queries.

You should add a line after that something like this

```
if ($dana > 0) {
  // do your delete queries
} else {
  // do nothing echo error
  echo "No movie found";
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote to this, I'd suggest error handling to match negative instead of else positive. `if(!$dana)` makes more sense when coding, and makes any code easier to follow. Just my opinion, of course!

Comment: After I added the if statement you mentioned I now get a following error:

No movie foundError: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bazus`.`film_producent`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ass_2` FOREIGN KEY (`filmy_id`) REFERENCES `filmy` (`id`))

film_producent has two fields: cofoundername and movie_id where movie_id (filmy_id here) comes from movie (filmy here) table. This is the only one having problems as all other ones do not give this error.

Comment: @user3318865 Well, it would seem that it does not find the movie. If you do `echo $id;`, what does it say? Does the result from that match anything in the database?

Comment: I have fixed the error adding "ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" in right place, and it works *almost* fine.

Now this query: $findel="DELETE FROM `bazus`.`filmy` WHERE `filmy`.`id` = $getid ;";

It doesn't delete the filmy (movies) table row when used from php script but it works when adjusted and used from myPHPadmin SQL query processor. What could be wrong with it? Thanks again for feedback.

I have added "die" and other error handling but I am 100% positive they're fine as I am using them to remove other table rows and they work just fine. This is only one left with a problem.